# Evaluating the integral $ \int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2 + 3}}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to integrate the following:

$$
\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2 + 3}}}dx
$$

It seems to me to be a trig  substitution; however, I couldn't seem to get it into one of the three forms, i.e., 
$$\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$$
$$\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}$$

I also tried integration by parts. If I made $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2 + 3}}$ and $dv = x$, the next integral was more complicated, and if I made $u = x$ and $dv = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2 + 3}}$, I was again unsure how to integrate the 1/sqrt term.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Set  $$\sqrt{2x^2+3}=u$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The square plus constant beneath the square root in the denominator definitely suggests that a trig substitution is helpful!  However, if we notice that the numerator is almost the derivative of what's under the denominator, the problem falls apart.  Set $$u = 2x^2+3.$$

Comment: do you mean $u=2x^2+3$? Sorry I am confused..

Comment: Yes, of course.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

$$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+3}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\underbrace{\frac{4x}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3}}}_{\text{of the form} \  \frac{u'}{2\sqrt u}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+3}}{2}+C$$

Answer (score 5):

$$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+3}}dx $$
Let $u=\sqrt{2x^2+3}$, then
$$ \frac{d}{dx}u=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{2x^2+3}}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}du=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+3}}dx $$
So now we have
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int du= \frac{1}{2}u+C = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2x^2+3}+C $$